# PowerShell: how to run script on a remote server?

Tags: events, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script:

```
$StartDay = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
Get-EventLog -LogName application -EntryType Error, Warning -After $StartDay
```

which I would like to run from my computer (Win XP, PowerShell 1.0) on a Server1 and Server2 (Win 2008, PowerShell 2.0). How can I run this command on these servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have administrative credentials on remote computer .

```
$StartDay = (Get-Date).AddDays(-2)
Get-EventLog -LogName application -EntryType Error, Warning -After $StartDay -computername REMOTESERVERNAME
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to user PowerShell remoting you need PowerShell 2.0 installed both on the server and on the client.

Check out these links. They are a good start into PowerShell remoting:

- [Remoting with PowerShell QuickStart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/10/remoting-with-powershell-quickstart.aspx)
- [Windows PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)